# Get-Content and/or ConvertFrom-Csv issue

Tags: powershell

I have the following CSV file example:

> 000001    ,a        ,b       ,c,               ,              ,
>   000002    ,d        ,e       ,f,               ,              ,g
>   000003    ,g        ,h       ,i,               ,              ,j
>   000004    ,k        ,l       ,m,               ,              ,n

I have an extract of my code below:

```
        Get-Content $Source |
        ConvertFrom-Csv |
                %{ $header = $false } {
                      $cv = $null;
                        $ColValue = $_.PSObject.Properties.Value | %{ if ($_) { $_.trim() } else { '' } }
                        if ($ExtractColumns -ne $null -and $ExtractColumns -ne "")
                        {
                            ForEach ($ExtractColItem in $ExtractColumns) {
                                ForEach ($ColValueItem in $ColValue) {
                                  if ($ExtractColItem -eq $ColValue.IndexOf($ColValueItem))
                                    {
                                        {
```

The code worked perfect until it came across a csv file similar to the one I sampled out. The 1st line contains 4 valued items (column 5, 6 and 7 been blank) the **$_.PSObject.Properties.Value** representation reaches to the end of column 4. The rest of the lines in the file then also get read to column 4 instead of all the way to 7.

AM I missing something? How can I fix it?

Comment: I think this can happen only if your csv doesn't have a header line with all the columns, which is an invalid file.

Comment: Ok thank you for responding. I will ry to fix it by placing imaginary column header names. I thought thaere would be a parameter of some sort to force it to read to the end of line.

Comment: ConvertFrom-Csv [-InputObject] <PSObject[]> [[-Delimiter] <Char> ] **[-Header <String[]> ]** [ <CommonParameters>]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** Using Eris's help from the the comment. Comment follows:

```
ConvertFrom-Csv [-InputObject] <PSObject[]> [[-Delimiter] <Char> ] [-Header <String[]> ] [ <CommonParameters>]
```

Thank you Eris. The Stack Overflow community has helped me. Should of used it more often from before... :-)